# Applications/protocols using same port same IP addresses at the same time

Tags: python, linux, networking, tcp, namespaces

I have a single interface on a device and I need to send out traffic from this interface at the same time. With below requirement

src address , destination address, source port, destination port and protocol needs to be same

So in my linux VM I use namespaces and i have this configured as below

```
ip netns eng51 ifconfig
eth1.51   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng52 ifconfig
eth1.52   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng522 ifconfig
eth1.522  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng511 ifconfig
eth1.511  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

so i have one script which tries to send some messgaes on destination namespace. I run python SimpleHTTPServer on destination namespace and on the source namespace I use python's socket and bind any address to port 63999

```
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0',63999))
```

this way I can control my source port to be always 63999. and I now run this script on source namespaces like

```
ip netns eng51 abc_client.py 51.51.2.10
ip netns eng511 abc_client.py 51.51.2.10
```

but problem I am facing is, even though I start the tcp session under 2 separate namespaces, port 63999 is not being considered unique. When the tcp session is in-progress under eng51 namespace and I start eng522 , the eng51 session is stopped saying connection reset by peer.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working by simply using multiple interfaces, mapping each interface of a VM to a namespace. And then I was able to use source port 63999 at the same time in 2 simultaneous sessions

ip netns eng51 ifconfig
eth1.51   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng52 ifconfig
eth2.52   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng522 ifconfig
eth3.522  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng511 ifconfig
eth4.511  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0